# How to get email alerts when a monitor goes down on NetScaler?

Tags: email, netscaler

How to get email alerts when a monitor goes down on NetScaler?

I am looking for a way to get email notifications when different things go wild with backend services served by a NS instance.

NS already has complex monitors so is there a way to use them to send emails?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK NetScaler can not do this by itself. (Or only on the obcenely large SDX boxes.)

So your best bet is to install the free "Citrix Command Center" software. It works as a Syslog/SNMP server and is used for NetScaler/CloudBridge fleet management and can also do e-mail notifications.

- Forums thread: http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/350390-netscaler-load-balncing-services-monitoring/ (Archived [here](https://archive.li/cuncP).)
- Citrix Knowledge base, *How to Configure Email Alerts on Command Center*, https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX215359 (Archived [here](https://archive.li/dPLhS).)